# Unable to read content of the file

Tags: c, file

I'm trying to print the contents of the file `x1.txt` using `fgetc` but it isn't working.

```
int main(void)
{
    FILE *x;
    char ch;

    x = fopen("x1.txt", "r");

    if (x == NULL)
    {
        printf("unable to access the file\n");
    }
    else
    {
        while (!feof(x))
        {
            ch = fgetc(x);
            printf("%c", ch);
        }
        fclose(x);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I'm still considered a beginner.

Comment: Is there any error?

Comment: You are misusing [feof()](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5431941/3185968)

Comment: This program suffers from the PASCAL disease: eof() is not known before you read something, but only after an unsuccessful attempt.

Comment: `c` should be an `int` because `fgetc` returns an `int`, not a `char`.